# Web scraping job portal in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am web scraping a job portal website. It is returning the same result even if i change the keyword search criteria. It seems i am doing something wrong in the code below -

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
uastring <- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"
session <- html_session("https://freesearch.naukri.com", user_agent(uastring))
form <- html_form(session)[[2]]
form
form <- set_values(form, EZ_KEYWORD_ANY = "SAS")
url <- submit_form(session,form)
sas_indeed <- url

# Get names of candidates
candidate_title <- sas_indeed %>% 
  html_nodes("#titleF") %>%
  html_text()
```

In the EZ_KEYWORD_ANY input value, if you change it from SAS to any keyword, it would return the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if rvest will work with this site - I haven't had a lot of luck using rvest for "interactive" web scraping like this.  You could try an RSelenium solution like this:

```
library(RSelenium)

#this sets up the phantomjs driver
pjs <- wdman::phantomjs()

#open a connection to it
dr <- rsDriver(browser = 'phantomjs')
remdr <- dr[['client']]

#go to the site
remdr$navigate("https://freesearch.naukri.com")

#enter search term
formObj <- remdr$findElement(using = 'id', value = 'ez_keyword_any')
formObj$sendKeysToElement(list("SAS"))

#submit search
submitObj <- remdr$findElement(using = 'id', value = 'findResumes')
submitObj$clickElement()

#get all names
names <- remdr$findElements(using = 'id', value = 'titleF')

#function to extract names
getName <- function(element){
  return(unlist(element$getElementText()))
}

#apply to all name elements
lapply(names, FUN = getName)
```

I only tested this on Ubuntu, so I'm not sure if there are any additional Windows/OS requirements for setting up RSelenium.  If you're using linux, this should be the only setup you need.